# Share table with all users with Realm Object Server

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

I have tried to share a table between users, basically I just want a table that every users could read and write. I have tried to remove the "~" in the table but I can't see this table on the Realm Object Server. This table does not seem to synchronized on ROS. I'm pretty sure someone has already done that :/
I've tried to use "SyncPermissionValue 2.7", does not work :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't see the database on Realm Object Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950997/cant-see-the-database-on-realm-object-server)