# Can't see the database on Realm Object Server

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

I have created a method to manage shared table between all users however I can't see this table. I have just remove the "~" character, it works if I leave the "~" character but the table it's only visible by the owner. I don't know why it does not work. Maybe it's not the proper way to share a table between users?

```
    static public func setGlobalDatabase(database:String,  completion: @escaping (_ realm: Realm?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {

    let realmPath = RealmService.REALM_SERVER_DATA + "/" + ConstanteService.APP_DOMAINE + "-" + database
    let user = SyncUser.current
    if user == nil  {
        SyncUser.logIn(with: .usernamePassword(username: RealmService.username, password: RealmService.password, register: false), server: URL(string: RealmService.REALM_SERVER_HTTP)!) { user, error in
            guard let user = user else {
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {


                // Open Realm
                let configuration = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: URL(string: realmPath)!))



               let permission = SyncPermissionValue(realmPath: realmPath,  // The remote Realm path on which to apply the changes
                    userID: "*", // The user ID for which these permission changes should be applied
                    accessLevel: .write)   // The access level to be granted
                user.applyPermission(permission) { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        // handle error
                        return
                    }
                    // permission was successfully applied
                }


                completion(try? Realm(configuration: configuration), nil)
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Open Realm
            let configuration = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user!, realmURL: URL(string: realmPath)!))
            completion(try? Realm(configuration: configuration), nil)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to grant permissions for user's realm to other users (`~/shared_user_realm`) you need to retrieve permissions on other users' devices first to get the full path to `shared_user_realm` and use it for `SyncConfiguration`. See more at https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#access-control

In case you want to have shared global realm (like `/shared_realm`) you should create it with admin user (only admins have an access to `/`) and grant permissions to other users. After that you can use this realm in your app.